# While uploading excel file in SAS, it round off the decimal places for example there is column Loading and value is 7.5% and it changes to 8%

Tags: sas

```
proc import datafile='/***/Port/Safeguard_Discount_Grid.xlsx' out=Safeguard_Dis_Grid1
dbms=xlsx
replace;
run;
```

This code is using for importing excel file where value of Loading is changes to 8% while in file it is 7.5%. Please suggest how to keep original data.

Comment: We can't guess what you're doing, how you import the file, how it's transformed or even if there's any rounding. It could be that the UI displays `7.5` rounded up, without actually changing the value

Comment: Provide example file that has the problem as I cannot reproduce it..  Also how are you checking the value?  Did you print the value?  What format did you use with the variable?  If you print 7.5 with a format that displays zero decimal places it will round up to 8.

Answer (score 1):

It probably isn't changing the values.

Run proc contents and check the format, then change it as necessary to show the full value as desired.

```
proc contents data=Safeguard_Dis_Grid1;
run;

data Safeguard_Dis_Grid1;
set Safeguard_Dis_Grid1;
format Loading percent12.1;
run;
```